# Ranking array base on key php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of object "$arr" like this:

```
Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
       (
           [1] => 1
       )

   [1] => stdClass Object
       (
          [0] => 1
       )

   [2] => stdClass Object
       (
          [4] => 2
       )

   [3] => stdClass Object
       (
          [3] => 2
       )

   [4] => stdClass Object
       (
          [2] => 3
       )

)
```

What I want to do is rank the value based on the key. If key($arr[$idx+1]) < key($arr[$idx]) then increase value of $arr[idx] by 1. So the results would look like:

```
Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
       (
           [1] => 2
       )

   [1] => stdClass Object
       (
          [0] => 1
       )

   [2] => stdClass Object
       (
          [4] => 5
       )

   [3] => stdClass Object
       (
          [3] => 4
       )

   [4] => stdClass Object
       (
          [2] => 3
       )

)
```

this is what I have done so far:

```
$arrIdx2=[];
foreach($arrIdx as $key=>$value){
    $newVal = new stdClass();
    $newVal->$key = $value;
    $arrIdx2[] = $newVal;
}

foreach($arrIdx2 as $key=>$value){
   $i= key((array)$value); 
   $m = $value->$i;  //get the first value
   for($j = $key+1; $j< $len; $j++){
       $i2 = key((array)$arrIdx2[$j]); //get the key of second value
       $n = $arrIdx2[$j]->$i2;
       if($n == $m){
          if($i2 < $i){
             $arrIdx2[$key]->$i += 1;
          }
       }
   }
}
```

and this is the result I got:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
       (
            [4] => 3
       )

    [3] => stdClass Object
       (
            [3] => 2
       )

    [4] => stdClass Object
       (
            [2] => 3
      )

)
```

What's the best way to do this? Can anyone guide me? Thanks

Comment: `If key($arr[$idx+1]) < key($arr[$idx])` not clear. can you draw a figure/ table of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

> Do this with associative array. I can't make an object array
>   right now. If you provide me the object array then i will update my answer.

**Try this:**

```
$arr = array(
            array("1" => 1),
            array("0" => 1),
            array("4" => 2),
            array("3" => 2),
            array("2" => 3)
        );

$out = array();
$first = key(current($arr));
$end =  key(end($arr));
foreach($arr as $key => $val){  
    $comp = (key($val) == $end) ? $end : key($arr[$key+1]);

    if($comp <= key($val))
        $out[$key][key($val)] = key($val) + 1;
    else
        $out[$key][key($val)] = $val[key($val)];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [4] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [3] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [2] => 3
        )    
)
```

I think you want this, let me know.

Comment: hi I really appreciate for your answer @FrayneKonok. However, what I want is actually comparing the key inside of each "inside" array. For example: the `key($arr[0]) = 1` and the `key($arr[1])=0`. Then, since the value of `$arr[1][0] < $arr[0][1]`, increase the value `$arr[0][1]` by 1. Thus `$arr[0][1] = 2`, and I want to this for the rest of the array.

Comment: the last index should be checked for the previous entry of the array too I guess, so the whole array will contain unique value. I'm not sure how to do this. Is there a way to do this recursively?

Comment: previous entry of the array means the entry of $arr[$firstindex] until $arr[$lastindex-1]..Sorry it's too confusing

Comment: @zangetsKid, Now check, everything okey.

Comment: hi this works with the data I gave above, but if the array looks like this:
`Array( [0] => Array([1] => 0)  [1] => Array([0] => 1) [2] => Array([4] => 2  ) [3] => Array ([2] => 2) [4] => Array([3] => 3))
`
Result is:
`Array([0] => Array([1] => 2)  [1] => Array([0] => 1) [2] => Array([4] => 5       ) [3] => Array([2] => 2) [4] => Array( [3] => 4))`